# Why is (10^(-10)) == -4

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate something and want to check if the difference between two numbers is smaller than `10^-10`. It didn't work, so I used `std::cout << (double)(10^-10)` and it printed `-4`. Is this the correct behavior? How could I change it so that it actually results in `0.0000000001`?

Comment: If you wanted exponentiation, you use `std::pow` from `<cmath>` (or, as I just saw from user786653, scientific notation). What you are doing in `10^(-10)` is bitwise XOR.

Comment: I'm stumped why it returns -4, though. Dec 10 should be bin 00001010, dec -10 = 11110100, and 10^(-10) would be 11111110 (-2). Assuming 2's complement, but that's practically universal.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`^` is exclusive or in C. For constants you probably want to use [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) `1e-10`. For varying exponents `std::pow` is, as the other answers say, the solution.

Comment: Simplest and easiest solution.

Comment: Wow that was fast! I think I go with this one, as Ed says it seems to be the simplest and easiest. Thanks everyone.

Comment: +1 Scientific notation. No need to involve a function call when integer literal will do.

Answer (score 5):

The `^` operator is the bitwise xor operator; it doesn't do exponentiation. You can use the `pow` function in `<cmath>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`^` is XOR.

Use `std::pow` for exponents:

```
std::cout << std::pow(10.0, -10);
```